# Normal Form question

Tags: normalization

Hey guys I am trying to study for an exam and I cant seem to get my head around normal forms.

here is one question:
R1 [a b c]
fd1: {a,b} -> {c}
fd2: c -> b

I know the candidate keys are
{a,b}
{a,c}

But how do i determine what normal form this is in?

Answer (score 1):

Surely, choosing {a,b} as key, R(X) is in 3NF

Using an alternative definition of 3NF:

### 3NF Relation

A Relation Schema R(X) is in 3NF if for every non-trivial FD Y->Z

- Y contains a candidate key (Y is superkey)

Or

- Z is a prime attribute (Z is part of a key)